# I/O Crash Error in XenServer VM. What to do?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, xen

I just installed XenServer 6.2 and installed XenCenter in my own Windows and everything were set ok.

I have 2TB 5400rpm SATA Hard Disk Drive, and I am trying to run 32 VMs at once using Xen environment, I am trying to check benchmarking performance on VMs with a vGPU installed on it. I had K1 NVIDIA Graphics card, and it supports up to 32 VM at once.

So, in order for a further research, I tried to install 32 VM at once, and run the benchmark, and I will try to see the difference between many VMs doing benchmark at the same time, versus only one VM working with one benchmarking.

So what I do was :

Installed Windows 7 ( 64-bit )
Put necessary files, installed NVIDIA Driver for K1
Copied that VM into other 31 pieces ( using fast-clone )
Trying to boot everything at once, and runa benchmark
But here's the case, The XenServer Crashed, and I found out that I/O was broke, I connected to SSH and even try to reboot it, the whole I/O was down, and I had to restart the machine via hard reset.

So, my question was

1. Are my steps correct?  I saw some article that saying that we can't just copy a VM like that.
2. How do people usually boot VMs?  If lets say you're about to open 32 VMs, can you just copy that Base VM and run it at once?
3. Why would the I/O operations crashed?  I have enough RAM and enough Hard Disk Drive space for it. 4. Am I still able to boot 32 VMs and do benchmark like this?

By the way I am using Supermicro 2027GR-TRF model with 128GB DDR3 Ram installed.

Comment: From my experience, XenServer is *extremely* bad at distributing I/O equally to VMs. Well, with a single disk, you’re SOL no matter what. ;)

Comment: so are you suggesting to have like more disk together in order to have large copies of VM's?

Comment: Absolutely. I believe what you’re doing isn’t I/O-heavy, but running 32 VMs from a single disk is rather... bold. I also experienced I/O starvation in my test runs, where a single VM (which ran fine) blocked everything else.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly wouldn't expect a host crash, but have you verified what happens with a single VM?  Does GPU passthrough work?  Did you install the NVIDIA drivers just in the VM, or also the dom0 components?  One of the big things to remember is that these big GPUs are power hungry and it's entirely possible that when you stressed the card that you starved the system.

Comment: GPU passthrough works, i used several benchmarks with 4 VMS with K260Q ( i installed K2 inside my machine. )

in order to find more detailed stuff, i just wanted to try to open 32 VMs at once and run it all at the same time, and do the benchmark at the same time, and trying to find out whether it will reduce performance if i did that. But what i found out is that the VM won't even boot, i tried to start 32 Vms at the same time, it is booting everything, but it tooks forever, and in the middle of the process, the I/O broke and its destroyed..